# Error NU5012: Unable to find 'Autofac.4.9.4.nupkg'. Make sure the project has been built

Tags: packages, nuget

Generando un paquete Nuget + Symbols me aparece el error : ***Error NU5012: Unable to find 'Autofac.4.9.4.nupkg'. Make sure the project has been built.***

El comando para generar el paquete es el siguiente:

```
nuget pack "C:\ruta\al\fichero\fichero.csproj" -Verbosity detailed -Symbols -SymbolPackageFormat snupkg -Version 0.0.18
```

Tengo otros proyectos, generados con el mismo comando y no me salta el error. El proyecto sobre el que se ejecuta el comando es un *proyecto .NetFramework*, con su archivo **.nuspec generado**

El .nuspec de configuración es el básico, sin dependencias.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>Autor</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>La descripcion</description>
    <copyright>Copyright 2020</copyright>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este error da por una ruta demasiado extensa en el .csproj